# How to combine Model and Data Parallelism on Multi-nodes GPUs using Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I have a 8-nodes computing-cluster, with each node has 4 GPUs (a total of 32 GPUs, each with only 16Gb memory). I am using Pytorch for my project. I can do data parallelization using DistributedDataParallel on all 32 GPUs, but the neural network model I am training is too large to fit into one GPU memory, so the data parallelization not help here. I tried to do Model parallelization to cut my model to 4 parts, but I can only run it on one node with 4 GPUs, with the data parallelization. But I can not figure out how to combine the data and model parallelization on multi-nodes. Does anyone know any examples (minimum viable example) or ideas how to do this?

Currently, I think the best way to move this forward is to do this in two steps (or two levels):
(1) do the model parallelization on one node (4 GPUs)
(2) replicate the model in step one to all the 8 nodes using DistributedDataParallel to do the data parallelization

Do you think the above idea is a good way to go? Is there an example how to do this?